# Google Marketplace SDK - Test Install Flow issue

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have created an app in the Google Apps Marketplace SDK and now I have the "Test Install Flow" button, which is fine,. however, when I click it, a popup for business account signup appears and asks me to set up a real Google business account. How can I simply test it with the same developer account I have?

Comment: I am also encountering this - I am logged in with a free 30 day trial Google for Work account, though, having filled out the sign-up box yesterday, but the test install flow button still takes me to the signup page.

Comment: just solved this: I was somehow logged into some of the google sites with my regular google account and some with my Apps for Work google account. Logging out of everything and logging in from scratch sorted it.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. It occurs when you first log in to Google with a non-Google Apps account (like a free Gmail account), after which Google Apps accounts are added (i.e. are logged in).

As Ben Clifford suggests in comments, one needs to be signed in first with a Google Apps account (after logging out completely). As a best practice, use Google Apps accounts in one web browser, and free Gmail account(s) in a different browser - to avoid further issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have to test it with a Google Apps account.  Apparently yours is not one of those, so they're asking you to sign up.  If you have a different Google account that has Google Apps already, you can add that account to the project in Permissions -> Add Member, and then use "Test Install Flow" while logged in as that other account.